# Парсинг - регулярные выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер

С помощью регулярных выражений извлеките из обеих строк названия городов и улиц, номера домов и квартир. Распечатайте результат.

Подсказка

Для поиска города и улицы заключите в круглые скобки выражение \w+, а для поиска номера дома и квартиры — выражение \d+.
Если окончание слов меняется или его вовсе нет, то в шаблоне напишите слово без окончания, а в конце поставьте .? — обозначение любого символа, который либо присутствует, либо отсутствует.
Любую последовательность символов (до первого перевода строки) обозначайте .*.

Можете пожалуйста помочь разобраться в задаче.

```html
import re
...

addresses = [
    ('Он проживал в городе Иваново на улице Наумова. ' 
     'Номер дома 125 был зеркальной копией его номера квартиры 521'),
    'Адрес: город Новосибирск, улица Фрунзе, дом 321, квартира 15.'
]

for address in addresses:
    Напишите регулярное выражение.
    pattern = r"(\w+)"
    
    Примените метод регулярных выражений, который 
    найдёт шаблон pattern в строке address.
    address_match = re.search(pattern, address)

    Распечатайте названия городов и улиц, номера домов и квартир
    из обеих строк.
    print(address_match)
```

Comment: Чтобы помочь - нужно, чтобы были какие-то ваши наработки, а иначе - это не помощь, а эксплуатация)

Comment: Сейчас допишу, я начал с того что пытался спарсить только названия городов, но не могу понять как парсить слово следующее за словом город. По слову город он поиск делает, а дальше не пойму.